# Adium sending two chat messages from applescript

Tags: applescript

I'd love to send my Adium contacts messages from the command line. The syntax should look like `echo test | im <contact>`. I've taken and modified [this script](http://frefo.blogspot.com/2008/07/replacement-script-for-zwrite-using.html) to do what I want, but it's a little old and I'm trying to modernize it. So far, I've got this working (I only changed the applescript, here.)

```
set stdinText to do shell script "echo \"\$MESSAGE\"" without altering line endings

tell application "Adium"
    set user to get contact "$BUDDY"

    if not (exists (chats whose contacts contains user)) then
        if not (exists (first chat window)) then
            tell account of user
                set new_chat to make new chat with contacts {user} with new chat window
            end tell
        else
            set existing_window to first chat window
            tell account of user
                set new_chat to make new chat with contacts {user} in window existing_window
            end tell
        end if
    else
        set new_chat to first chat whose contacts contains user
    end if

    send new_chat message stdinText
end tell
```

Works well, except that the chat message is sent twice. Is this a bug in Adium or am I doing something wrong in applescript?

Comment: Judging from [Adium’s AppleScript docs](http://trac.adium.im/wiki/AppleScript_Support_1.2), your script could probably be simplified, but I can’t see anything likely to cause a double send in it. OTOH, there is [no ticket for an Adium bug sounding remotely like your issue either](http://trac.adium.im/query?status=assigned&status=new&status=pending&description=%7EApplescript&group=type&col=id&col=summary&col=status&col=owner&col=type&col=milestone&order=priority). I wonder if something in your specific configuration causes the issue (double chat sessions being created maybe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also ran up against this bug, where Adium was sending the chat message multiple times.

It's caused by more than one running background process named AdiumApplescriptRunner.  Apparently only one of these processes is supposed to be running at any given time, but sometimes more than one starts up, and when this happens you get a duplicate chat message sent for each extra AdiumApplescriptRunner process.

My work around was to create a cron task, that runs every minute, and executes this bash command:

```
ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep 'AdiumApplescriptRunner' | awk '{print $2}' | awk 'NR == 2,/c/' | xargs -I %s kill -9 %s
```

This command makes sure only one process named AdiumApplescriptRunner is running, and kills any but the one that Adium created.